# How long to short RUN pin on pi zero to initiate boot?

Tags: boot, power, pi-zero, reset

I've been working to design something that can automatically short the RUN pin to GND when I want to turn my pi zero on from a full poweroff. The RUN-GND short works well to turn it on, but does anyone know how long that short should/can be held? I have read a few comments about pushing it into a safe mode if you hold RUN to ground for too long.

Comment: I think I've read before that it could be hold in reset forever.